groq.APIConnectionError: Connection error
I am using Langchain and Groq for LLM project but I am getting API connection error, although I imported:
import os
load_dotenv()

and then loaded API as:
groq_api_key = os.getenv("GROQ_API_KEY")
os.environ["GROQ_API_KEY"] = groq_api_key

Still, I am getting this error
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 72, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    yield
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 236, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection_pool.py", line 216, in handle_request
    raise exc from None
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection_pool.py", line 196, in handle_request
    response = connection.handle_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py", line 99, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py", line 76, in handle_request
    stream = self._connect(request)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py", line 154, in _connect
    stream = stream.start_tls(**kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpcore\_backends\sync.py", line 152, in start_tls
    with map_exceptions(exc_map):
  File "C:\Users\z004vrff\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.0\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpcore\_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from exc
httpcore.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\_base_client.py", line 972, in _request
    response = self._client.send(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 926, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 954, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 991, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1027, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 235, in handle_request
    with map_httpcore_exceptions():
  File "C:\Users\z004vrff\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.0\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 89, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\gradio\queueing.py", line 536, in process_events
    response = await route_utils.call_process_api(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\gradio\route_utils.py", line 322, in call_process_api
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1935, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1520, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(  # type: ignore
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 56, in run_sync
    return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 2405, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 914, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\gradio\utils.py", line 826, in wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\groqLLM.py", line 186, in respond
    response = agent_with_chat_history.invoke(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 5343, in invoke
    return self.bound.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 5343, in invoke
    return self.bound.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 3022, in invoke
    input = context.run(step.invoke, input, config)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 5343, in invoke
    return self.bound.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 4706, in invoke
    return self._call_with_config(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 1923, in _call_with_config
    context.run(
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\config.py", line 396, in call_func_with_variable_args
    return func(input, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 4572, in _invoke
    output = output.invoke(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 5343, in invoke
    return self.bound.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 170, in invoke
    raise e
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 160, in invoke
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1629, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1335, in _take_next_step
    [
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1335, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1363, in _iter_next_step
    output = self._action_agent.plan(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 464, in plan
    for chunk in self.runnable.stream(inputs, config={"callbacks": callbacks}):
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 3405, in stream
    yield from self.transform(iter([input]), config, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 3392, in transform
    yield from self._transform_stream_with_config(
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 2193, in _transform_stream_with_config
    chunk: Output = context.run(next, iterator)  # type: ignore
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 3355, in _transform
    yield from final_pipeline
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 1409, in transform
    for ichunk in input:
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 5550, in transform
    yield from self.bound.transform(
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 1427, in transform
    yield from self.stream(final, config, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 418, in stream
    raise e
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 398, in stream
    for chunk in self._stream(messages, stop=stop, **kwargs):
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_groq\chat_models.py", line 509, in _stream
    for chunk in self.client.create(messages=message_dicts, **params):
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\resources\chat\completions.py", line 287, in create
    return self._post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\_base_client.py", line 1244, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\_base_client.py", line 936, in request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\_base_client.py", line 996, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\_base_client.py", line 1073, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\_base_client.py", line 996, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\_base_client.py", line 1073, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\z004vrff\OneDrive - Siemens Healthineers\DQM\venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\_base_client.py", line 1006, in _request
    raise APIConnectionError(request=request) from err
groq.APIConnectionError: Connection error.

I already updated the certif
also, tried:
SSL Error Fix:
Go to this file in your environment
Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py

Do this - update the code like below in the merge_environment_settings function
verify = False #merge_setting(verify, self.verify)

after download modify it back
verify = merge_setting(verify, self.verify)

after downloading modify it back to original
I tried everything but the SSL error still not going. I am also using huggingface embedding model which works with no issue. Please help!
